# no matching function error using template template parameters in a function

Tags: c++, templates, metaprogramming

I'm trying to define a function using template template parameters (I just want to know how it works). I have the following:

```
template <typename T, template <typename> class Cont>
typename Cont<T>::iterator binary_search (typename Cont<T>::iterator first, typename Cont<T>::iterator last)
{
    typename Cont<T>::iterator it;
    // ...
    return it;
}
```

Then in the `main ()` function:

```
std::vector<int> data;

// ....

std::vector<int>::iterator it = binary_search (data.begin (),data.end ());
```

I get this error when trying to compile the code:

```
binary_search.cpp: In function ‘int main(int, char**)’:
binary_search.cpp:43:83: error: no matching function for call to ‘binary_search(std::vector<int>::iterator, std::vector<int>::iterator)’
```

I cannot find any appropriate response that helps me to sort out this error. Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Nop. Just in case I've just changed the function name to `my_binary_search ()` and it doesn't work either.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you have is a non-deduced context, aswell as a template template parameter mismatch even if the context was deducible. `std::vector` takes a second template parameter, the allocator, that is defaulted to `std::allocator`.

For the non-deduced context, `T` can never be deduced and will always have to be specified, the `typename` indicates this. [See this question for the gory details.](https://stackoverflow.com/q/610245/500104)

Comment: Hi, thanks very much for the clarification. Is there any way to work around the parameter mismatch? (and thanks also for the link, it's really useful)

Comment: Just template on the iterators, that's all you need. `template<class Iter> // done`.

Comment: Yep, finally I had a look at the STL header files and did it that way: `  template<typename _ForwardIterator, typename _Tp, typename _Compare>
    bool
    binary_search(_ForwardIterator __first, _ForwardIterator __last,
                  const _Tp& __val, _Compare __comp)
`

Comment: @user: No, no, and *no*. Don't use `_This` or `__this` naming convention, it's reserved by the standard for the implementation. Just drop the underscores.

Comment: I didn't use them, just copied & pasted from the STL header file :)

Comment: @user: Oh, okay, then nevermind. But using such a naming convention is one of my pet-peeves. :)